# Linq with EF core 2.2 Condition with where Clause FK and PK

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Hi im having the problem in using the where clauses with a FK and PK bacuse the FK from InstalltionÍnformation is a Object. And i cant understand it.
The `i => i.ImportRunID` is a iqueryable and cant convert to int `ImportRuns.ImportRunId`

```
var Aggnone = context.ImportRuns.Select(IR => new
                        {
                            ImportRunId = IR.ImportRunId,
                            ExtractedDate = IR.ExtractedDate,
                            ProcessDate = IR.ProcessDate,
                            ProcessResult = IR.ProcessResult,
                            FailureDescription = IR.ProcessResult,
                            InstallationInformationIDFK = context.InstallationInformation.Select(II => new
                            {
                                InstallationInformationID = II.InstallationInformationID,
                                LicenceKey = II.LicenceKey,
                                ProductVersion = II.ProductVersion,
                                ProductName = II.ProductName,
                                CompanyName = II.CompanyName,
                                Timestamp = II.Timestamp
                            })
                        }).Where(x => x.ImportRunId == context.InstallationInformation.Select(i => i.ImportRunID);
```

The equivalent in MSSQL(What should be)

```
 Select * from ImportRuns as IR
 left join InstallationInformation as II 
 on IR.ImportRunId = II.ImportRunId
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
context.InstallationInformation.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ImportRunID).InstallationInformationID
```

instead of

```
context.InstallationInformation.Select(i => i.ImportRunID)
```

Comment: it has still a error.
"Cannot implicity convert type 'Dbcontext.ImportRunTable' to 'bool'"
"Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return"